# Switching between 3rd party servers

Tags: managed-package, app-development

I need to switch my managed app between dev and prod servers (not SF servers but my company servers). I would like prod server URL to be the default URL for callouts but to keep the opportunity to sometimes switch to dev for development and testing purposes.

I don't really want to keep this flag in a public custom setting inside my MP or hardcode it, are there better ways to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a protected custom setting -- which wouldn't be visible to the subscriber. However, you'd need to provide a facility for editing this value (VF page, most likely) and someone snooping around could probably find their way to this page.

Sfdcfox covers the other options in his https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/38888/2533